# PHPStorm with Xdebug: break to debugger on change of variable value

Tags: breakpoints, xdebug, phpstorm, watch

I see how to set a breakpoint with a condition that controls breaking. But that means I have to set a breakpoint at a specific point. Is there a way to set a break on the change of a variable value, no matter where that change occurs?

In other debuggers, this seems to be a standard feature.